# URL structure of Joomla menu and sidemenu

Tags: url, menu, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

I can't seem to get my URL structure the way I want it.

I have the following structure for my category/articles

Trends
-Subtrend
--Article
--Article
-Subtrend
--Article
--Article

et cetera.

My main menu has a menu item called 'Trends' with a submenu which shows the 'subtrends'. When I click one of these menu items my url is domain.com/trends/subtrend, this is exactly how I want it.

However on some pages I have a sidemenu which only shows the subtrends as menuitems, when I click one of those menu items my url is domain.com/subtrend, but I want it to be domain.com/trends/subtrend. Just like how my category structure is made and how my main menu shows it.

I read that Joomla 'creates' it's URL structure based on the menu structure, but how do I fix my URL structure so that the sidemenu links to the same type of links as my main menu.

Mind you I don't consider using external links and inserting them manually to be a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem right you have two different menus? Let me call them 'Trends'
 and 'TrendsSide' for the sidemenu.

To keep the structure domain.com/trends/subtrend you have to edit each entry in TrendsSide and use 'Menu Item Alias' for each Subtrend. Then you have to choose the identical menu entry from the original Trends menu.

Now you have two different menus but each entries of the 2nd points on one entry of the first menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using sh404sef:

Sh404sef > Configuration > General > by Components > Tags ADD “tags/” in the text box.

Example:

BEFORE - https://castle-rock-lake.com/adams-county.html

AFTER --> https://castle-rock-lake.com/tags/adams-county.html